# Highlighting a div class around the selected radio button?

Tags: jquery

What jQuery functions add a class to one div.card element if one radio button is checked?
It's not about clicking, because one already checked element should always be highlighted (ex. after page load) :-)

```
<div class="col-lg-6 form-check">
    <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-header">Headline<small class="text-muted">Subline</small></h3>
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <img class="card-img-left" src="{{ asset('img/image.png') }}">
            <div class="card-block">
                <p class="card-text">Desciption</p>
            </div>
            <input class="hidden-xs-up" type="radio" name="character" value="1" checked>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: the goal: highlight a checked area]

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/ and after page load its all about how you approach it with your back-end stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all `.card` elements that are parents of a checked radio button using [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').closest('.card').addClass('checked')
```

As the documentation says:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Here is a little, very simplified, demo.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').closest('.card').addClass('checked')
```

```css
.card {
  background: grey;
}

.card.checked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <label><input type="radio" name="character">Character 1</label>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <label><input type="radio" name="character">Character 2</label>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <label><input type="radio" name="character" checked>Character 3</label>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <label><input type="radio" name="character">Character 4</label>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <label><input type="radio" name="character">Character 5</label>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Of course, you still need to update that class when the state of the checkboxes changes. This simplified demo shows how that could be done.

```js
// set initial state
var $checked = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
$checked.closest('.card').addClass('checked');

// update on change
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
  $checked.prop('checked', false).closest('.card').removeClass('checked');
  $checked = $(this);
  $checked.closest('.card').addClass('checked');
});
```

```css
.card {
  background: grey;
}

.card.checked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <label><input type="radio" name="character">Character 1</label>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <label><input type="radio" name="character">Character 2</label>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <label><input type="radio" name="character" checked>Character 3</label>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <label><input type="radio" name="character">Character 4</label>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <label><input type="radio" name="character">Character 5</label>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I also feel a bit more confident with jQuery now! Would you give me a last cookie by shortly explaining why this small piece of code has to load after the jQuery file? Or is there another way like document.ready()? makes it sense to load addClass BEFORE jQuery itself? It feeld weird to embed this small code a the end of the document/after jQuery :)

Comment: Sure! jQuery needs to be loaded because we use its functions, so those need to be defined. The document also needs to be loaded, otherwise the elements that we want to change the class of are not loaded yet. jQuery indeed has a callback for this, check out [this page](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for details. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the box is checked and use .addClass() like so:

```
if($('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('.card').addClass('selected');
};
```